# Is every basis of a finite-dimensional vector space orthonormal with respect to some inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given a real or complex vector space $V$ and a (finite) basis $B$ of it, does it always exist an inner product on $V$ such that $B$ is an *orthonormal* basis with respect to it?

The question is equivalent to asking: is there always a positive definite (symmetric) matrix $A$ such that if $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, then

$$v_i^tAv_j=\delta_{ij}\;?$$

Comment: Yes. You can define the inner product via $<v_i,v_j>=\delta_{ij}$. You would have to check that this indeed defines an inner product. The matrix $A$ is related to how you move from one basis to another.

Comment: @ThomasRot Could you precise please?

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. On the $\mathbb{K}$-linear space $V$, an inner product is a bilinear form $\varphi \, : \, V \times V \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{K}$ which is symmetric positive definite. Let $B = \big( \varepsilon_{1},\ldots, \varepsilon_{n}\big)$ be a basis of $V$ and let $(x,y) \in V^{2}$. We can write :

$$ x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \varepsilon_{i} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad y=\sum_{j=1}^{n} y_{j}\varepsilon_{j} $$

where $(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}) \in \mathbb{K}^{n}$ and $(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n}) \in \mathbb{K}^{n}$. By bilinearity of $\varphi$, we have :

$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x,y) &= {} \varphi \Big( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \varepsilon_{i} \, ,\sum_{j=1}^{n} y_{j}\varepsilon_{j} \Big) \\[1mm]
 &= \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} x_{i}y_{j} \varphi \big( \varepsilon_{i},\varepsilon_{j} \big) 
\end{align*}
$$

As a consequence, in order to define $\varphi$, one must specify the value of $\varphi(\varepsilon_{i},\varepsilon_{j})$ for all $i$ and $j$. Choosing : $\forall i,j, \, \varphi(\varepsilon_{i},\varepsilon_{j}) = \delta_{i,j}$, you obtain an inner product on $V$ for which $B$ is an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this for the real case. A vector $x$ can be written as
$$
x=\sum_i x^i v_i
$$
where $x^i$ are real numbers. Then for another vector $y=\sum_i y^iv_i$ we can define an inner product via the formula

$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_i x^i y^i.
$$
The formula in my comment above is the same expression. I only defined it for the basis vectors, and assumed a bilinear extension of it.

Comment: But under this definition of the inner product $\;\langle ,\rangle\;$ we may well have that $\;B\;$ is *not* orthonormal...

Comment: @Timbuc: I think it is. Take $x=v_i$ and $y=v_j$. Then $x^i=1$ and $v^j=1$, and $\langle x,y\rangle=\delta_{ij}$.

Answer (score 0):

I use your equivalent question ie finding symmetric matrix A s.t. if B={v1,...,vn} , then

$v_i^tAv_j=\delta_{ij}\;$

We know $A$ has $(n^{2}+n)/2$ unknown parameters (same as the number of equations we have) and It is so easy to prove that if such an $A$ were exist It is always positive definite. So It is suffices to show that this system has a solution. You know I prove it (It is better to say some calculations instead of proof) for $\;V\;$=$\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with direct method and think It can be proven for other dimensions similarly.

Suppose $v_1=[a_1,a_2]^t,v_2=[b_1,b_2]^t,\mathbf{A}=\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{x}_{1}&{x}_{2}\\
{x}_{2}&{x}_{3}
\end{array}\right]$

then we obtain $\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{a}_{1}^2&2{a}_{1}{a}_{2}&{a}_{2}^2\\
{a}_{1}{b}_{1}&{a}_{1}{b}_{2}+{a}_{2}{b}_{1}&{a}_{2}{b}_{2}\\{b}_{1}^2&2{b}_{1}{b}_{2}&{b}_{2}^2
\end{array}\right]$$\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{x}_{1}\\
{x}_{2}\\{x}_{3}
\end{array}\right]$=$\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0\\1
\end{array}\right]$

It is not difficult to show that left $3$ by $3$-matrix is invertible ($v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent) and We have always exactly $1$ solution. Only thing remains is to show for dimension $n$ this $(n^{2}+n)/2$ by $(n^{2}+n)/2$ matrix is invertible (:

Answer (score 0):

Another answer with a slightly different approach: what you're asking about here is a statement on [bilinear forms](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) or [sesquilinear forms](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form), in the complex case. For convenience, I'll stick to the complex case, but all of this can, with care, be handled in the case of a real vector space.

Note that an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot):V \times V \to \Bbb C$ on a complex vector space $\Bbb C$ is simply a sesquilinear form with the additional property that:

- $(x,x) \geq 0$ for all $x$
- In the real case: $(x,y) = (y,x)$ (this follows from the above over $\Bbb C$)
- $(x,x) = 0 \iff x = 0$

From there, we use the fact that every sesquillinear form can be written as 
$$
(x,y) = x^* Ay
$$
for some complex matrix $A$, whose entries are
$$
a_{ij} = e_i^* A e_j
$$
By the above, the three requirements on our sesquilinear form are **precisely** the statement that $A$ is positive definite.